# Android, animate spinner dropdown items

Tags: android, animation

Is it possible animate drop down items in android? For example rotate which row with it's container (not just inside view!). when you animate `convertView` of the `getDropDownView` inside the adapter, it just animate inner view.

Comment: " For example rotate which row with it's container" it doesn't say anything to me...

Comment: I mean rotate first row, after a second rotate the second row and so on...

Comment: see ViewGroup#startLayoutAnimation()

Comment: have you got any solution to your question